# How to convert camelCase attribute name to angular's dashed-case attrubute

Tags: angularjs, dom, attributes

I have a custom Angular service which creates a custom DOM node using `angular.element()`. Meanwhile, since I also want the element to have a set of predefined attributes, I pass a JS object as a second parameter to the function:

```
var element = angular.element('<node-name />', {
   class: "some css class",
   onclick: "someClickHandler()"
});
```

Although this works OK as far as the attribute is not specific to Angular.

The problem is that I'm not able to produce Angular-like ***dashed-case*** (*don't know what their actual name is*) attributes (e.g. `ng-click`).

For now, if I do:

```
 var element = angular.element('<node-name />', {ngClick: 'someClickHandler'});  // ng-click here is definitely not possible as it leads to a syntax error
```

it will always result in the DOM node as:

```
<node-name ngclick="someClickHandler"></node-name>
```

which doesn't work the Angular way.

***So, is there any way that a camel-case attribute be converted to its equivalent dashed-case in the DOM?***

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need any additional code to convert from camelCase to snake-case (although you could). It's better to use snake-case in the first place if you really want to, just make sure you put property name in quotes, otherwise the name is not valid identifier:

```
var element = angular.element('<node-name />', {
    'ng-click': 'someClickHandler'
});
```

Comment: Didn't notice at all wrapping the _key_ in quotes. :)